# test bench is no working. z and x states in modelsim

Tags: sorting, verilog, fpga, modelsim, quartus

i realized a bubble sort code on verilog. there are no any synthesis erorrs, but test bench is not working in modelsim. it  shows x and z states

```
module sort #(
    parameter NUM_VALS = 5,
    parameter SIZE     = 16
)(  input  wire clk,
    input  wire [NUM_VALS*SIZE-1:0] in,
    output reg  [NUM_VALS*SIZE-1:0] out
);
    reg [NUM_VALS*SIZE-1:0] sorted_bus;
    always @(posedge clk) begin
        out <= sorted_bus;
    end

    integer i, j;
    reg [SIZE-1:0] temp;
    reg [SIZE-1:0] array [1:NUM_VALS];
    always @* begin
        for (i = 0; i < NUM_VALS; i = i + 1) begin
            array[i+1] = in[i*SIZE +: SIZE];
        end

        for (i = NUM_VALS; i > 0; i = i - 1) begin
            for (j = 1 ; j < i; j = j + 1) begin
                if (array[j] < array[j + 1]) begin
                    temp         = array[j];
                    array[j]     = array[j + 1];
                    array[j + 1] = temp;
                end 
            end
        end

       for (i = 0; i < NUM_VALS; i = i + 1) begin
            sorted_bus[i*SIZE +: SIZE] = array[i+1];
       end
    end
endmodule
```

testbench

```
module sort_tb;
    reg clk;
    reg  [16-1:0] in1,  in2,  in3,  in4,  in5;
    wire [16-1:0] out1, out2, out3, out4, out5;

    sort #(.NUM_VALS(5), .SIZE(16)) dut (
        .clk(clk),
        .in ({in1,  in2,  in3,  in4,  in5}),
        .out({out1, out2, out3, out4, out5})
    );

    always @(posedge clk) begin
        in1 <= 1;
        in2 <= 5;
        in3 <= 8;
        in4 <= 3;
        in5 <= 2;
    end

    always @(posedge clk) begin
        $display("In:  %0d %0d %0d %0d %0d", in1,  in2,  in3,  in4,  in5);
        $display("Out: %0d %0d %0d %0d %0d", out1, out2, out3, out4, out5);
    end

    initial begin
        #100;
        $finish;
    end

    always begin
        clk = 1'b0; #5;
        clk = 1'b1; #5;
    end
endmodule
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

@dduy_le, I am just looking at your ModelSim screen and it looks to me like you haven't actually started the simulation.  I think it is saying, everything is compiled successfully and it is sitting at time = 0.  If you put your clock on the waveform, (Right click over clock and send to Waves) you will be able to verify if that is the case or not.  If it does show that you have not pulsed the clock yet, you can hit the run (next to the 0 PS time box) and that should start the sim.  Then you need to make sure you run it long enough to see the rising edge from the clock.  That clock edge should set your IN values to valid values per your posedge clock statement in your testbench.